# SQL RDL IIF condition to check for null

Tags: sql, null, rdl, iif

I want to display "X" if the field has a certain text, and "" if not.

I have tried this but shows #Error when field is null:

> =IIF(Fields!ReasonNonCompliance.Value.ToString().Contains("Assessment Personnel;"),"X","")

I have tried this with the same #Error.

> =IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Reason.Value),"",IIF(Fields!Reason.Value.ToString().Contains("Reason
> Assessment;"),"X",""))

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure for rdl, but most other SQL technologies blank and NULL are 2 different things.  You may need to check for NULL value (unless that what the IsNothing is doing?